# Is there a way to immediately populate an object property from associated ID field when instancing an object from the DB?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

Say I have two tables on my SQLite DB, **Person** and **Student**.

Person has the columns **Id** and **Name**.
Student has the column **Id** and **PersonId**. **PersonId** evidently links to the **ID** column in the Person table.

So in my app, I have a class for each of these tables, **Person** and **Student**.

Student class will have the properties:

```
public class Student
{
Int Id { get; set; };  
Int PersonId { get; set; };  
Person person { get; set; };  
}
```

And then I have my SQLite connection to fetch my data from the DB:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(DBLocation);
var students = con.Table<Student>().ToList();
```

This will fill both "Int Id" and "Int PersonId" properties on each object, but not the "Person person" property.

My question is, is there a way to assign this property (Person person) its respective value (a Person object whose Id == Student.PersonId) at the same time? Or what would be the best practice for doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use ORM like EntityFrameworkCore, you can achieve this.
Student class:

```
public class Student
{
Int Id { get; set; };  
Int PersonId { get; set; };  
Person person { get; set; };  
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
Int Id { get; set; };
Student Student { get; set; };  
}
```

Then by using it:

```
var person = new Person
{
  Id = 1,
  Student = new Student
  {
    Id = 1
  }
}

dbContext.Persons.Add(person);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

There are some configuration to be done before you can use the code, like creating DbContext child class which represents the database in the memory etc.  You can learn EF Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: I can already do that with SQLite though. Currently I'm doing it in the Get method of the property, something like `return con.Get<Person>(PersonId)`. What I was wondering was if there's a more immediate or simply better way of doing it.

Comment: This way which I have showed you is related to inserting of related items. For getting related items, you can do: ```dbContext.Persons.Include(p => p.Student).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == PersonId).```